# Implementing express graphql api with Gatsby graphql

Tags: express, graphql, gatsby

So I am building an app using express js ,graphql, postgres and react. And I have already build my backend but now instead of using react, I want to use GatsbyJs how do I connect my express graphiql with my Gatsby graphiql or send my data directly to Gatsby graphiql

Comment: Please show your code or what have you done so far. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-graphql/

Comment: @ksav thank you i just started learning gatsby and  that helped

Comment: @shakirkhan I'm glad it helped. Good luck with the app

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-graphql",
      options: {
        // This type will contain remote schema Query type
        typeName: "MyGraph",
        // This is the field under which it's accessible
        fieldName: "myGraph",
        // URL to query from
        url: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

Then in say  index.js  make the query

```
export const query = graphql
  query {
    myGraph {
      users {
        name
        age
      }
    }
  }
```